Firefox browser multi-line go backward and forward through command history shortcuts
Using console developer tools, it seems that in multi-line mode there's no shortcut for navigating through command history as you could with arrow keys. Currently, I'm trying to find in the source code where there are defined shortcuts or this CLI functionality. Is there a way to configure shortcuts?  I guess there will be no conflict if I add a composed shortcut like ctr+upArrow.
From the docs:
https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/the_command_line_interpreter/index.html#execution-history

In single-line mode, use the up and down arrows. 
In multi-line mode, use the ⋀ and ⋁ icons in the editing panel’s toolbar.

